# My .java code works in IntelliJ IDE but not in Terminal

Tags: java

Please note that I don't have a vast amount of knowledge of Java so please do be patient with me.
This is my first posting.

There are two .java files attached below:

Here is flappyBird.java

```
package flappyBird;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class flappyBird implements ActionListener {

    public static flappyBird flappyBird;

    public final int WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 800;

    public Renderer renderer;

    public Rectangle bird;

    public flappyBird() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Flappy Bird!");
        Timer timer = new Timer(20, this);

        renderer = new Renderer();

        frame.add(renderer);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        bird = new Rectangle(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2, 20, 20);

        timer.start();
    }

    public void repaint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.cyan);
        g.fillRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);

        g.setColor(Color.orange);
        g.fillRect(0,HEIGHT-120, WIDTH, 150);

        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect(0,HEIGHT-120, WIDTH, 20);

        g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        g.fillRect(bird.x, bird.y, bird.width, bird.height);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        flappyBird = new flappyBird();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }
}
```

Here is the Render.java

```
package flappyBird;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Renderer extends JPanel {


    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        flappyBird.flappyBird.repaint(g);
    }
}
```

And when I try to run the program *IN TERMINAL* , my terminal says:

```
this@is-AF-AK3U-S3R:~/Desktop/Flappy Bird/src/flappyBird$ java flappyBird.java
 
flappyBird.java:23: error: Renderer is abstract; cannot be instantiated
        renderer = new Renderer();
                   ^
flappyBird.java:25: error: no suitable method found for add(Renderer)
        frame.add(renderer);
             ^
    method Component.add(PopupMenu) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Renderer cannot be converted to PopupMenu)
    method Container.add(Component) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Renderer cannot be converted to Component)
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
2 errors
error: compilation failed
```

And as I have said In the title, the IntelliJ IDE runs it just fine, is it using a different code that what I am using in the terminal?
Please let me know If I have to provide anymore information.

Comment: You need to first **compile** the code using `javac`, then **run** the code using `java`. You can't run `.java` source files directly. --- I high recommend you go through a standard "Hello World" **tutorial** to learn how to build and run Java programs.

Comment: @andreas the latest jdk can run Single file java files directly. May be useful here if appropriately adapted.

Comment: And this is the problem here: **Single** file java files

Comment: @Andreas Since java 14 (or 13?) you can run Java files directly using `java SomeClassName.java`, the script should be self-contained though (or at least not rely on other local source files)

Comment: I would support the point of @Andreas. Latest JDKs truly do that, however, it's *crucially* important to understand what really happens behind the scenes. As a bare minimum, Java developer should know what is `.class` file and how it differs from `.java` one. Just to make something work, because latest JDKs compile them with one `java` command, is not the best idea.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I know, but this has 2 files (`flappyBird.java` and `Renderer.java`), so you can't use that feature, and I didn't want to confuse OP by mentioning it. --- Don't confuse the [`javax.swing.Renderer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Renderer.html) *interface* imported by `import javax.swing.*` with the **`flappyBird.Renderer`** class that the code is attempting to use. The compiler is making that mistake, *because* it is in single-source mode.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Problem is that the code is not self-contained, since it needs to use the `flappyBird.Renderer` *class* instead of the `javax.swing.Renderer` interface.

Comment: @Andreas I know that, but you said _"You can't run .java source files directly."_ (denying that possibility entirely), which is not the case anymore since recent Java versions.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes, I meant what I said, you can't run .java source file**s** *(plural)* directly. Sure, I might have clarified by acknowledging that you can run a *single* .java source file directly since Java 11 ([JEP 330: Launch **Single-File** Source-Code Programs](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330)), but since this question has multiple source files, my statement stands.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not compiling the Renderer class before trying to run it. You first need to compile with `javac` and then run with `java`. See here: https://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/first-java-program/

Comment: Better: Use a build manager - nobody in real life manually invokes javac, because it is a pain. Grab a template file for maven or gradle, read a "getting started" guide and build your program the way the pros do. (Or, if you don't want to deal with that right now - just keep running in IDE, because that also takes care of that problem.)

Comment: OP is still learning Java and sure there are a million better ways than running javac manually but if OP wants to understand why his method is not working, this is the way to do it. Otherwise, I'm sure even OP understands that they can keep using their IDE.